# Black screen when changing HTML5 video src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I'm trying to change video source with javascript and set the currentTime to the time when the src changed but I get a black screen on Chrome and a freezing screen in Firefox with a weird sound like when I change src. If I remove

```
$("#video").on("canplay",function(){
             video.currentTime = time;
         });
```

it works fine.

```
<video src="http://srv35.clipconverter.cc/download/tdCQhWZj2IqwZGpolpWUaXFk5KWmqWxt4pSXaWlmnGhkZnK0qc%2FMqHyf1qiZpa2d2A%3D%3D/Blunt%20%26%20Real%20ft.%20Ledri%20Vula%20-%20Nese%20m%27don%20ti%20-%20Remix%20%28Official%20Video%20HD%29.mp4" id="video" autoplay></video>

<div id="360p" class="quality">360p</div>
```

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var time;

var _360p = "http://r3---sn-p5qlsnel.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ratebypass=yes&sparams=id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,mime,mm,ms,mv,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&ipbits=0&mt=1410631565&sver=3&itag=18&expire=1410653286&mm=31&upn=vTh5FN82i_U&id=o-AJXkFxYoWM1bFEPoTrX53eNVZbgtwutGGXv655WRWj4Q&mime=video/mp4&initcwndbps=1202000&ip=2001:41d0:2:40c5:a8b1:cb97:ef0b:b1b4&key=yt5&fexp=900147,927622,931983,932404,934030,936117,945539,946023,947209,952302,953801&source=youtube&mv=m&ms=au&signature=A77C56E95778206A0A06799B860CECFAE8A35ED8.C27AA1B748D371DFCC52DA1219133F63FDBDABB4&&title=Blunt+%26+Real+ft.+Ledri+Vula+-+Nese+m%27don+ti+-+Remix+%28Official+Video+HD%29";

var _1080p = "http://srv35.clipconverter.cc/download/tdCQhWZj2IqwZGpolpWUaXFk5KWmqWxt4pSXaWlmnGhkZnK0qc%2FMqHyf1qiZpa2d2A%3D%3D/Blunt%20%26%20Real%20ft.%20Ledri%20Vula%20-%20Nese%20m%27don%20ti%20-%20Remix%20%28Official%20Video%20HD%29.mp4"; 

video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    time = video.currentTime;
});

$("#360p").click(function() {

    $("#preload").attr("src", _360p)

    $("#preload").on("canplay",function(){
        $('#video').attr("src", _360p);
     $("#video").on("canplay",function(){
         video.currentTime = time;
     });
    });



});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cc88530p/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting video.src and video.currentTime are likely to result in calls to the timeupdate and canplay handlers. I think you want to unregister the timeupdate handler before setting video.src, and probably unregister the video.oncanplay handler before setting video.currentTime. (I can't test this in your jsfiddle because the googlevideo URL returns 403 Forbidden.)